# Why does fit_transform() always give me zeros?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm wondering why the following:

```
sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform([[58,144000]])
```

gives this result:

```
array([[0., 0.]])
```

I'm doing a Logistic Regression where I run `fit_transform()` on array of values (the actual data file) like the ones above. Yet, that transform seems to work fine. But when I try to do a single pair of values as shown above (`[[58,144000]]`), I get zeros.

For predictions using a "new" input, I need to scale that new value the same way as the test/train data were scaled so my ML predictions will work.

Thanks for suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: I am not sure if this answers your question, but if you have already fit  a `standard_scaler=StandardScaler()` object to your training data and you want to transform your new data then you should do `standard_scaler.transform` instead of `StandardScaler().fit_transform`.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html), you may wondering, why does it expect a 2D array? You can compute mean and standard deviation of a vector, which is a 1D array, as you reflect it on your question. The answer is, it expects (samples, features) data.

So, in case where you pass data like `[[58,144000]]`, it is  a `(1,2)` array which means 1 sample with 2 features. Then it will fit transform each feature, which is a single number. Normalizing each feature give you a zero: `[[0., 0.]]`.

On the other hand, if you pass the data like `[[58],[144000]]`, then it will be `(2,1)`, which means 2 samples and 1 feature. Then it scale and standard each feature, and give you the result as you may expected like: `[[-1],[1]]`.

```
x = [58,144000]
mu = np.mean(x)
sigma = np.std(x)
print([((58 - mu) / sigma),((144000 - mu) / sigma)]) # [-1.0, 1.0]

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
print(StandardScaler().fit_transform([[58],[144000]])) # [[-1.] [ 1.]]
```

Comment: One of the problems I had was this code: from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScalar()
gives me the error "name 'StandardScalar' is not defined"

Comment: Its not StandardScalar(), its `StandardScaler()`. Scalar is wrong, Scal**e**r is ok.

Comment: Thanks, partially works, but gives wrong result. From the A-Z machine learning class,
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()

print(classifier.predict(sc.fit_transform([[49, 28000]]))) -> is zero, when it should be one.

Comment: Have you ever read my answer? I told, if you pass the array like this [[49, 28000]], It consider this as two features for 1 sample. Then both of them in transformation will be zero. It should be [[49], [28000]]

Comment: Yes, I read it, but your suggestion did not work. Using your suggestion, I get: " X has 1 features per sample; expecting 2"

Comment: Note that in prediction, you should not use `fit_transform`. Instead you should use `transform`. 1. define `sc = StandardScaler()` 2. Apply on train dataset by `sc.fit_transform(train_x)` 3. While predicting use only transform `classifier.predict(sc.transform([data]))`.

Comment: test_data = np.array([[32], [150000]]).reshape(1,2) seemed to be required to get the array in the correct dimensions. Then shape is (1,2). However the classifier.predict(sc.transform(test_data)) always returns zero. Thanks.

Comment: This is just a single pair of values as "new data" to predict in the LR model.